# I can't create a true variable in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have this code in javascript I can't make the final part work!
If i answer red it won't show the first option!
I am new in Javascript so I am a little bit confused!
But I can't find the mistake!

```
var myName = prompt("Whats your name?");

var greeting = function (name) {
    alert("Hello" + " " + name + "!");
};

greeting(myName);

var askFavColor = prompt("Whats your favorite color" + " " + myName + "?");

var red = true;

if (askFavColor === red) {
    alert("Really that's mine too!!");
} else {
    alert("Mine is Blue" + " " + myname);
}
```

Comment: `prompt` always returns a string. A string is not a boolean.

Comment: remove the line `var red = true;`, and it should work fine  and change `askFavColor === red` to `askFavColor === 'red'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the thing you asked for.

```
var myName = prompt("Whats your name?");

var greeting = function (name) {
    alert("Hello" + " " + name + "!");
};

greeting(myName);

var askFavColor = prompt("Whats your favorite color" + " " + myName + "?");

var red = "red";

if (askFavColor === red) {
    alert("Realy thats mine to!!");
} else {
    alert("Mine is Blue" + " " + myName);
}
```